# Archivos React (.JS) y Archivos (.EJS)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, ejs, transbank

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en react con bootstrap, y la situación es la siguiente:

- al hacer clic en un botón con react necesito que se  inicie un flujo de pago en transbank.
  este es el repo de TBK para node donde viene un ejemplo [tbk node](https://github.com/TransbankDevelopers/transbank-sdk-nodejs-webpay-example.git)

y el ejemplo viene realizado en una plantilla .ejs que correo sobre express.

aqui llama a iniciar la transacción:

```
 <span><a class="text-blue-600 hover:no-underline underline" href="webpay-normal/init">Iniciar transacción</a></span>
```

y se inicia el flujo de pago.

lo que necesito hacer es eso mismo pero desde mi archivo .js se inicie la transacción:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Instructions extends Component {
  handleClick (e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(e.nativeEvent)
    alert('acá se debe iniciar la transaccion')
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h4>Eventos</h4>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>iniciar transaccion</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

su ayuda ya sea con algún video de youtube, link o lo que sea para resolver este problema que tengo , desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso lo puedes conseguir con una llamada js común:

```
  handleClick (e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(e.nativeEvent)
    window.location.pathname = "webpay-normal/init"
  }
```

Aunque si lo quieres hacer es una transición con react puro, deberías probar a implementar [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) en tu proyecto y luego hacer algo como:

```
TuComponente.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
  // ...

  handleClick (e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(e.nativeEvent)
    this.context.router.transitionTo("webpay-normal/init")
  }
```

Comment: gracias, lo probare.